# Maven connection refuse

Tags: maven-3, maven-release-plugin

I am getting below error at the time of maven build process. If anyone have idea how to resolve this, please let me know. Thanks.

### Error:

```
[ERROR]  Unresolveable build extension: Plugin com.vmware.o11n.mojo.pkg:maven-o11n-package- plugin:5.5.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for com.vmware.o11n.mojo.pkg:maven-o11n-package-plugin:jar:5.5.2 (): Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6: Could not transfer artifact org.slf4j:slf4j-parent:pom:1.6.6 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refused: Connection refused: connect -> [Help 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems com.vmware.o11n.mojo.pkg:maven-o11n-package-plugin:jar:5.5.2 not valid. You can try with [Plug-in SDK](https://developercenter.vmware.com/web/sdk/55/vco). For more detail please refer questions [Q1](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2348930) , [Q2](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2381170) post on vmware community forum.